# Magento 1 - Free Shipping after applying Gift Card Code

Tags: magento-1, shipping, coupon-codes, free-shipping, gift-card

I've been struggling with an issue regarding **free shipping** and **gift card codes**.

So basically I have a `free shipping rule` which applies to orders **above $100,** based on `subtotal` after `applying discount codes`.
However, my issue is that Magento does not make a difference between `gift card codes` and `coupon codes`.
For example, I don't want someone applying a **gift $100 card code** to pay for shipping, but I want someone who places **$100 worth of products** in their cart and applies a **10% off coupon code.**

> Is there an extension or a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. The current gift card extension was from WebTex and the shipping rules was from Amasty so there is a bit of compatibility issue. As far as I could tell, getting the Amasty version would solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Magento treats these both cases same as **gift $100 card code** is also a product which you are buying and or gifting to some one.

You have to create some kind of logic to filter the gift card type of products.